# How user can remove selected date from popupdatefield in vaadin

Tags: vaadin

Suppose,User has  selected date from Popupdatefield and after that user want to remove the date from Popupdatefield .Then is there any option in Popupdatefield to do so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this is to manually select text inside the component and clear it using backspace, delete etc.
You can always add `Button` for user which programmatically clears the `PopupDateField` component value.